# derivative function in 4D data parameter netcdf

Tags: python-3.x, netcdf

I want to calculate derivative relative vorticity and u component wind 'diff (rv,u)' in data with 4D (time,level,lon,lat). I expect to derivative the parameter at each dimension. This is my error in py :

"The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

This is my script

```
import netCDF4
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy
import sympy as smp
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import pandas as pd
import scipy as sp
from scipy.misc import derivative

print('this worked')

# open netcdf file
nc = Dataset('D:/dataskripsi/medan_17_2021/nc/18.nc') 

# Check file
print(nc) 

itime = 26 # time step to calculate and plot

#defenisi parameter
u = nc.variables['u'] [:,:,:,:] #[ # Zonal wind [m/s]
v = nc.variables['v'] [:,:,:,:] #[itime, :, :] # Meridional wind [m/s]
rv = nc.variables ['vo'] [:,:,:,:] #[itime, :, :] # relative vorticity
vv = nc.variables ['w'] [:,:,:,:] #[itime, :, :] # vertical velocity
gp = nc.variables ['z'] [:,:,:,:] #[itime, :, :] # geopotensial
hgh= nc.variables ['level'] [:] # pressure level
lon= nc.variables ['longitude'] [:] # bujur
lat= nc.variables ['latitude'] [:] # lintang

nrv = np.array(rv[0])
nu  = np.array(u[0])


dx = np.diff (nrv, nu)
```

This is my data link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HDrcZAsMwJrbgaJwASSz07dSnVSpfJKK/view?usp=sharing